# Use of ただいま to others who are not physically present

Tags: word-choice, usage

Imagine that I live alone. Occasionally when I get home, I still want to announce that I'm home (such as with a text message) because perhaps my parents are making sure I got home safely or perhaps an online friend wants to do stuff together.

Would ただいま still be an appropriate announcement here? Or is there some other way to announce that I'm home to someone who is not physically present in the house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use 今家に着いたよ or something along those lines.

You do occasionally see (for example, in novels), a person say ただいま to an empty room to emphasize the speaker's lonesome state, such as if he's lost a loved one, or that he's simply feeling lonely, etc. but you won't be saying ただいま to someone who you're in conversation with.

A more modern youngster might well prefer something like 帰宅なう though... or is that already too old?

Comment: This is consistent with what I was expecting, though it sounds a little direct. Thanks.

Comment: You may also go with the like of 今家に帰ったところ, but overall it's going to be the same general idea.

Comment: I recall seeing 「帰宅」 in a tweet, but that is probably irrelevant with respect to the question's situation.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would text to them

to your friend

"たった今、家に着きました。"

I have arrived home just now.

たった今 means just now

safety confirmation to your parents

無事に家に着きました。

I have arrived home safely

無事に means safely

Hope it helps.